# Retrieving Session Token

Tags: java, session-cookies, sessionid

Is there a way of retrieving a session token from a website after authentication using java? Would something like an httpSessionListener work? I've need it done for usernames but not for session id's.

I am attempting to enter my credentials into a website, and then need once in, navigate to a different page within the site so that I can upload a file.

In my code, I am currently reading the webpage to ensure that I am getting to the correct site, but once I am logged in I can not navigate to a different page. It simply reads the main screen once logged in.

My thought around this was trying to retrieve the token issued from the website so that I would be able to navigate the site to the desired page; however, I am unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a `HttpServletRequest` object, it's easy.

```
String sessionId = request().getSession().getId()
```

Comment: Awesome! In what way would I need access to the HttpServletRequest? Simply by providing the proper username and password?

Comment: this answer assumes that you are the author of the website. if so, you should have access to the request object

Comment: What if I am not the author of the website? Am I S.o.L then?

Comment: No but the solution is different. Please add more details to your question